# Elementary syntax for (project in file(".")) in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

Is `project in file(".")` in SBT "short" for `project.in(file("."))`?

If I'm right, I'd like to know what the `in` method does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is `project in file(".")` in SBT "short" for `project.in(file("."))`

Yes, it is (it's actually not "short", it's called [infix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation)).

All the `in` method does is set the base directory for the project you're creating with a bunch of configurations and definitions:

```
/** Sets the base directory for this project.*/
def in(dir: File): Project = copy(base = dir)
```

And finally it ends up creating a new project definition for you (inside the `Project.unresolved` method):

```
new ProjectDef[ProjectReference](
  id, base, aggregate, dependencies, delegates,
  settings, configurations, auto, plugins, autoPlugins) with Project
```

And on top of that, you apply a bunch of settings and dependencies.